# Ajax -- Prevent 100 Continue Behavior

Tags: jquery, ajax, http

I have a Javascript application that POSTs reasonably large requests to a back end server.  Because (1) we know we want to receive all the requests on our non-public endpoint and (2) for various reasons the load balancer/proxies involved don't handle the Expect: 100-Continue header very cleanly, I'd like to tell the browser clients to never send the Expect: header.

Is there as way in jQuery or in the raw xmlHttpRequest object to instruct the browser to just POST the whole request body every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand you correctly and you are sending request via jquery $.ajax,
then you should be able to set headers like this:

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'your_url',
   type: 'post',
   data: your_big_data,
   headers:{
      'Expect': ''
   }
});
```

I have to say i have not yet needed to test this in javascript but similar workarounds works well in other cases. Let me know if that works.

Comment: We'll try to test this -- is there any documentation or spec someplace that explains how it works?  I'm assuming the empty header is supposed to supersede any automatically included headers, but it'd be nice if there was some authority for it somplace.

Comment: Haven't had a chance to test yet but it's the best shot we've got.  Thanks. :)